# CentOS host, OpenVZ CentOS container with its own IP cannot access internet

Tags: centos, virtualization, openvz

I'm running CentOS 6, and I've got OpenVZ installed ([installed with this guide](https://openvz.org/Quick_installation)). I'm new to virtualization, and I'm just using these containers for my own projects.

I followed all instructions in that guide.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I've created a CentOS 6 container using OpenVZ's CentOS 6 template. I also added an IP to the container and set up a nameserver.

Host's ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:A0:18:A8
          inet addr:107.161.123.162  Bcast:107.161.123.167  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:255699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40447 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:299527614 (285.6 MiB)  TX bytes:3249925 (3.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:28 Memory:fbce0000-fbd00000

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:A0:18:A8
          inet addr:107.161.123.163  Bcast:107.161.123.167  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:28 Memory:fbce0000-fbd00000

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:A0:18:A8
          inet addr:107.161.123.164  Bcast:107.161.123.167  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:28 Memory:fbce0000-fbd00000

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:A0:18:A8
          inet addr:107.161.123.165  Bcast:107.161.123.167  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:28 Memory:fbce0000-fbd00000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:158 (158.0 b)  TX bytes:158 (158.0 b)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:29817 (29.1 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Commands I used to create and start the container:

```
vzctl create 102 --ostemplate centos-6-x86_64
vzctl set 102 --ipadd 107.161.123.163 --save
vzctl set 102 --nameserver 8.8.8.8 --save
vzctl start 102
```

Container's ifconfig:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:2958 (2.8 KiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:107.161.123.163  P-t-P:107.161.123.163  Bcast:107.161.123.163  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

The container cannot access the Internet at all. It can ping its own IP (107.161.123.163), cannot ping the host IP, or 8.8.8.8.

I'm new to Linux virtualization. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Turns out that since the IP was bound to an interface on the host machine, it wasn't available to the container.